# identifing a plant with oval cut edge leaves and purple spotted green stems

Tags: identification, vegetables, leaves

I have a plant that has oval shaped leaves that are thickish and have hair. The edges are jagged cut when the leaves are small and grow less so as the leaf gets bigger. The stem is purple spotted and green. The stem on the two foot stems look like veins instead of spots.

Comment: I think a photograph of the plant in question would be very useful

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: It's occurred to me you could be describing Poison Hemlock (Comium maculatum), though there are other plants that have purple spotting and streaking on the main stems. Photograph or more info, as Niall asks, essential.

Comment: Is there any way we could make this easier for people?  This is their first visit and it is difficult to know what to tell us about the plant they want to ID.  How about a simple form to fill out and an easy way to upload pictures?

Comment: And I read 'purple splotches' that is exactly what comes to my mind, Bamboo!

Comment: Hemlock doesn't have oval leaves, though, so I think it must be one of the other many plants that have purple blotches on the stems.

Comment: @TeresaMcgH - you're right, it doesn't, but the word used was 'opal' prior to your edit (presumably meaning oval) but then there's 'jagged cut', so its not clear. We really need a photo as there seems to be somewhat of a language barrier.

Comment: Without pictures and prior guidance these people asking for ID must get awfully frustrated.  Would it be difficult to produce a new tab or option for those who want an ID on a plant? For instance; are the leaves opposite or alternate with a little drawing for explanation...where is this plant, in your garden, in the mountains, on the edge of a pond? What is your zone? Have a mini-link that they are able to put their address in and have it automatically added.  A simple way to upload a picture! A way for a more productive first visit?

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.